# "Action not defined in AppController" error when accessing a different controller with default route

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm super new to CakePHP so I have a feeling that I'm probably just doing something silly, but I've been stuck on a problem:

Following the tutorials, I created a controller called UsersController in cakephp/app/Controller/UsersController.php, and a model in cakephp/app/Model/User.php that corresponds to a users table in my database.  (Also created a view)  From what I understand, the default route to this should be:

> mysite.com/cakephp/app/users

However, when I go to that URL, I get the error

> The action *users* is not defined in controller *AppController*

If I add this to AppController...:

```
public function users(){
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));
}
```

...it will go to the right controller and everything is dandy, but I know that isn't the way it's supposed to work.  Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Double check that url is correct, as it does not look so.. try mysite,com/cakephp/users instead

Comment: Oh my god, I'm an idiot.  That did it!  I kept thinking I needed to have the 'app' folder in the url.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example, it should just be `www.mysite.com/users`  This will look for an index action in the users controller.

The "normal" url is `www.mysite.com/controller/action/variables`

You don't need to define anything in the AppController (for this example).

Comment: *Hides face in embarrassment* That did it.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry about it - we've all been there.